# Angular2 render app 2 times

Tags: meteor, angular

I have a problem, i can`t get into routing in Angular 2. Mb someone fased with something similar?

So, my app renders in a weird way:

```
<my-app><div> <app-nav-bar _nghost-ile-2=""><ul _ngcontent-ile-2=""> <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><li _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-style="[object Object]" style="float: left;"> <a _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-href="/" href="/">Home</a> </li><li _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-style="[object Object]" style="float: left;"> <a _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-href="/index/books" href="/index/books">Books</a> </li><li _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-style="[object Object]" style="float: right;"> <a _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="active" ng-reflect-href="/index/about" href="/index/about">About</a> </li><li _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-style="[object Object]" style="float: right;"> <a _ngcontent-ile-2="" ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-href="/" href="/">Login</a> </li> </ul> </app-nav-bar> <router-outlet></router-outlet><app-hello _nghost-ile-4="">
<html _ngcontent-ile-4="">
<head _ngcontent-ile-4="">
  <link _ngcontent-ile-4="" class="__meteor-css__" href="/merged-stylesheets.css?hash=d42394b95cde74014bba42c21ff2737c29b8fc61" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <base _ngcontent-ile-4="" href="/">
</head>
<body _ngcontent-ile-4="">
  <my-app _ngcontent-ile-4="">Loading....</my-app>
</body>
</html>
</app-hello> </div> </my-app>
```

As you can see, my-app>(app-nav-bar+app-hello)>html>(head+body) etc..

File main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from './app.routes'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

File app.routes.ts

```
import {

RouterConfig, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import {
    HelloComponent
} from './imports/index'

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', component: HelloComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

File app.component.html:

```
<div>
    <app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

File index.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <base href="/">
    <meta viewport>
</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading....</my-app>
</body>
```

If someone can help me, i will be very happy =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the right answer, but looks like i missed package, that allows me to use static template directly. So, replacing

```
import template from 'ex.controller.html'

@Component({
...
template,
...
})
```

With this

```
@Component({
...
template: 'ex.controller.html',
...
})
```

And deleted import helped a heavily.